# ¿Como Numerar una lista mientras cumpla una condición y luego reenumerar si es otra lista en MySQLWorbech?

Tags: mysql

Buenas, estoy trabajando con MySqlWorbench, y lo que busco es hacer una consulta que me devuelva una lista de forma numerada mientras todas las filas pertenezcan a una misma ciudad, pero si la ciudad cambia, que vuelva a numerar las filas hasta que la ciudad vuelva a cambiar.

Ejm:

1 - Los Angeles - Joshua Peyton 
2 - Los Angeles - Mike Sanderson 
3 - Los Angeles - Leon Piers 
1 - Washington - Chris Pitt 
2 - Washington - Alice Queen 
3 - Washington - Niki Partson 
4 - Washington - Susan Stone 
5 - Washington - Judith River 
1 - Texas - Lucy Clenfonper 
2 - Texas - Joshep Anderson

como se puede ver la numeración se reinicia cuando la ciudad cambia, eso es lo que busco, una vez hecho eso lo diferenciare por letras 'A001'... 'B001', para evitar errores PK. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Te recomiendo que añadas a tu pregunta el código que ya tengas hecho, así es más fácil ayudar. Saber le nombre de las tablas y/o campos facilitará que las respuestas estén más afinadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En otras bases de datos existe la clausula [OVER](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx) que determina una partición o rango de valores, sobre los que aplicar una función de ventana, o una función de agregado.

Por ejemplo: Numera los registros, creando una partición por ciudad, ordenado por ciudad. O sea, va numerando mientras no cambia la ciudad.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ciudad ORDER BY Ciudad)
```

En MySql no existe está funcion y debe realizarse usando variables. La ventaja es que las variables se pueden inicializar en la misma sentencia SQL.

Para este caso he usado una estructura como la que muestro a continuación:

```
create temporary table tt(poblacion text, nombre text);
insert into tt values
('Los Angeles','John'),
('San Diego','Lola'),
('Los Angeles','Pepe'),
('San Diego','Juan'),
('Los Angeles','Serena'),
('San Diego','Maria');
```

Y uso dos variables:

```
@cid: Es el contador de filas
@poblacion: Guarda el valor de la ultima ciudad leida.
```

La sentencia CASE lo que hace es:

Si la ciudad es igual que la anterior, incrementa en 1 el contador de fila.
 Si la ciudad es diferente reinicia @cid a 1.

```
select 
       @cid := case when @poblacion = poblacion then @cid + 1 else @cid := 1 end as cid,
       @poblacion := poblacion as p,
       nombre
from
    (select @cid := 1) i,
    (select @poblacion := poblacion as poblacion, nombre from tt order by poblacion) t
```

Y este es el resultado:

```
+-----+-------------+--------+
| cid |  poblacion  | nombre |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  1  | Los Angeles |  John  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  2  | Los Angeles |  Pepe  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  3  | Los Angeles | Serena |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  1  |  San Diego  |  Lola  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  2  |  San Diego  |  Juan  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  3  |  San Diego  |  Maria |
+-----+-------------+--------+
```

Pudes probarlo aquí: <kbd>[Rextester](http://rextester.com/ADLE62282)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias McNets!, pero necesito que @cid se reinicie cuando cambie el valor de poblacion. Tal y como lo hace la tabla que puse en mi pregunta, aumenta numericamente hasta que el valor del campo Población cambia, entonces se reinicia y vuelve a contar. Gracias de antemano McNets

Comment: @neojosh2 Aquí lo tienes, intentaré poner un poco de explicación a ver si me retiran el voto negativo

Comment: Magnifico! y sin hacer una función o un store procedure, brillante! muchas gracias McNets! :D!!!

Comment: McNets... tu respuesta me ayudo bastante, pero me dejo otra interrogante... 
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43954/mysqlworkbench-como-concatenar-numeraciones-de-listas-que-se-reenumeran-al-camb?noredirect=1#comment76276_43954

Comment: McNets, gracias por tu ayuda, funcionó y lo adapte a mi bbdd como un view, pero no me permite ordenarlo... http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51803/my-sql-workbench-mostrar-ultimas-filas-de-cada-ciudad

Comment: Hola @McNets, disculpa pero estoy teniendo dificultades con un query MySql que cuenta llamadas cada media hora de un día determinado (es para hacer llamadas diferidas), pero cuando no hay llamadas en una franja no logro que me muestre 0, solo muestra las franjas donde hay llamadas, llevo toda la madrugada tratando de resolverlo pero no lo consigo ni con un Left Join.

http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55065/mysql-mostrar-0-cuando-no-se-encuentre-llamadas-en-una-franja-horaria