# MySQLWorkbench-¿Como concatenar numeraciones de Listas que se reenumeran al cambiar el valor de un campo Con valores de un campo de otra Tabla?

Tags: mysql

Buenas, mi pregunta es un tanto compleja. Tengo el siguiente código (Muy agradecido McNets por la ayuda con la formula). :

```
select 
       @cid := case when @poblacion = poblacion then @cid + 1 else @cid := 1 end as cid,
       @poblacion := poblacion as p,
       nombre
from
    (select @cid := 1) i,
    (select @poblacion := poblacion as poblacion, nombre from Clientes order by poblacion) t
```

Que me devuelve los siguiente:

```
+-----+-------------+--------+
| cid |  poblacion  | nombre |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  1  | Los Angeles |  John  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  2  | Los Angeles |  Pepe  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  3  | Los Angeles | Serena |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  1  |  San Diego  |  Lola  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  2  |  San Diego  |  Juan  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|  3  |  San Diego  |  Maria |
+-----+-------------+--------+
```

Y en otra tabla llamada Localización tengo los siguientes valores:

```
+-----+-------------+---------+
|  ID |   Ciudad    |Iniciales|
+-----+-------------+---------+
|  1  | Los Angeles |    LA   |
+-----+-------------+---------+
|  2  |  San Diego  |    SD   |
+-----+-------------+---------+
|  3  |  New York   |    NY   |
+-----+-------------+---------+
```

Busco concatenar Las iniciales de la tabla Localizacion con los de la tabla Clientes.

Quedándome más o menos así:

```
+------------+-------------+---------+
|    Cod     |   Ciudad    |  Nombre |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|  LA000001  | Los Angeles |  John   |
+-----+------+-------------+---------+
|  LA000002  | Los Angeles |  Pepe   |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|  LA000003  | Los Angeles | Serena  |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|  NY000001  |  New York   |  Lola   |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|  NY000002  |  New York   |  Juan   |
+------------+-------------+---------+
|  SD000001  |  San Diego  |  Maria  |
+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Al hacer inner joins la formula no funciona,con case when, if, y un millón de parámetros sigo sin conseguir fusionar la formula indicada más arriba con la concatenación de las iniciales de la Tabla Localización, los ceros que irán desapareciendo conforme @cid vaya incrementándose, gracias de antemano!

Comment: Ya probaste con `CONCAT(Iniciales, ' ', cid)`

Comment: ¿Porque tienes que calcular el campo `cid` de esa manera? ¿No tiene la tabla `clientes` una columna que te sirva de identificador? bien raro si no lo tienes.

Comment: en realidad la tabla cliente no contiene la columna cid, cid es un parámetro que numera las listas de la tabla clientes para que estas se reinicien si el campo población cambia de valor, entonces volverá a numerar, lo que necesito es que el parámetro @cid, se concatene con las iniciales de la tabla Localización (LA, NY, SD)... teniendo que quedar así: LA000001 este resultado irá en una tabla como código primario.

Comment: Los nombres de las ciudades van a coincidir siempre?

Comment: si siempre el nombre de las ciudades con el numerador obtenido del conteo por Poblacion, el codigo compuesto permitira diferenciar cada cliente y generar su respectiva bitacora de cada uno de ellos por id de filtrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añadimos la tabla Localizaciones con un `LEFT JOIN` por si acaso los nombres no coinciden, con `LPAD` le ponemos 0 delante de cid, y usamos `CONCAT` para juntar las iniciales con el valor.

```
select concat(iniciales, lpad(cid, 6, 0)) as Cod, p as Ciudad, nombre
from
    (select 
           @cid := case when @poblacion = poblacion then @cid + 1 else @cid := 1 end as cid,
           @poblacion := poblacion as p,
           t.nombre,
           t.iniciales
    from
        (select @cid := 1) i,
        (select @poblacion := tt.poblacion as poblacion, tt.nombre, loc.iniciales 
         from tt
             left join loc on tt.poblacion = loc.poblacion 
         order by tt.poblacion) t
     ) t1

+----------+-------------+--------+
|    Cod   | Ciudad      | nombre |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| LA000001 | Los Angeles | John   |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| LA000002 | Los Angeles | Pepe   |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| LA000003 | Los Angeles | Serena |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| SD000001 | San Diego   | Lola   |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| SD000002 | San Diego   | Juan   |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| SD000003 | San Diego   | Maria  |
+----------+-------------+--------+
```

Aqui puedes verificarlo: http://rextester.com/JSZSN59277

Comment: Excelsior!, gracias McNets otra vez lo hiciste posible... ya lo probé rextester y funcionó a la perfección... lo correre en mi bbdd ahora mismo, otra vez muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Hay que tener mucho cuidado con las consultas que usan la técnica de las variables, sobre todo cuando comienzan a ser más complejas.

En realidad, MySQL no ofrece muchas garantías en cuanto al orden en que procesa las variables. Y en el caso de la respuesta de @McNets, aunque es muy interesante, te puede causar problemas sin aviso. Particularmente porque la consulta asume muchas cosas:

- Asume que el join va a procesar los registros en el orden especifiado dentro de la sub-consulta (`ORDER BY poblacion`)
- Asume que el resultado del join va a salir en el mismo orden especifiado dentro de la sub-consulta (`ORDER BY poblacion`)
- Asume que las variables en el `SELECT` son procesadas en el orden escrito.

Pero en realidad, esas cosas no están garantizadas, de modo que la consulta queda muy frágil. Nota lo que dice [la documentación MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) al respecto:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

Traducción mía:

> Como regla general, a menos que sea dentro de una sentencia `SET`, nunca deberías asignarle un valor a una variable y leer esta misma dentro de la misma sentencia.
>
> Para otras sentencias, como `SELECT`, puede que obtengas los resultados esperados, pero esto no está garantizado.
>
> No obstante, el orden de evaluación de las expresiones que contienen variables no es definido.

Obviamente, lo ideal hubiera sido poder usar funciones ventana como `ROW_NUMBER()`, pero MySQL no las tiene :(

Te propongo la consulta siguiente, que aunque no ofrece el mejor rendimiento, por lo menos te garantiza resultados estables. Nota que para que funcione correctamente, se necesita que la tabla `clientes` incluya alguna columna numérica que sirva de clave primaria (en esta caso, le puse una que se llama `id`). Si no la tienes, vale la pena agregar una, ya que no es buena práctica que tu tabla no tenga clave primaria de todas maneras:

```
select concat(l.iniciales, 
              lpad((select count(*) + 1
                     from clientes c2
                    where c2.poblacion = c.poblacion
                      and c2.id > c.id),
                   6, '0')) as cid,
       l.ciudad,
       c.nombre
  from clientes c
  join localizacion l
    on l.ciudad = c.poblacion
 order by cid;
```

Resultado:

```
|    Cod     |   Ciudad    |  Nombre |
---------------------------------------
|  LA000001  | Los Angeles |  Serena |
|  LA000002  | Los Angeles |  Pepe   |
|  LA000003  | Los Angeles |  John   |
|  NY000001  |  New York   |  Juan   |
|  NY000002  |  New York   |  Lola   |
|  SD000001  |  San Diego  |  Maria  |
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/MOJYKY56575)</kbd>

---

Nota aparte: sería recomendable no repetir el valor `ciudad` en ambas tablas. Mas bien, sería mejor si la tabla `clientes` incluye mas bien una columna `localizacion_id` o algo así, definida como foreign key hacia `localizacion.id`.

Comment: sstan si la tabla cliente tiene su propio indice, pero la tabla llamada bitacora es la que tendrá que filtrar a cada cliente por ciudad (podría hacer una tabla detalle bitacora pero son más de 7000 clientes ), asu vez cada cliente por ciudad y esta por estado, y por pais, y así sucesivamente, cada cliente tiene más de un detalle, no se adapta a la bbdd, tendré en cuenta el tema de garantía de las consultas, haciendo unos tests de rendimiento de la formula indicada, muchas gracias sstan !

Comment: Lo entiendo 100%. Es una limitación con el uso de MySQL.