# MySQL - Mostrar últimas filas de cada ciudad

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una vista que usa `LEFT JOIN` y `CASE WHEN` para juntar 2 tablas y mostrar una única vista compactada, el cual da como resultado el link que dejo aquí abajo.

http://rextester.com/RFG40822

Necesito que muestre el último resultado de cada ciudad. Más o menos así

```
| S_Cod  | Id |  poblacion  | nombre | Resultado |
|LA00001 |  3 | Los Angeles |John    | CONTRATO  |
|SD00001 |  6 | San Diego   |Lola    |DISUELTO   |
|LA00002 |  3 | Los Angeles |Pepe    |NO LOCALIZADO|
|SD00002 |  2 | San Diego   |Juan    |JUNTA |
|LA00003 |  5 | Los Angeles |Serena  |CANCELADO |
```

Aquí dejo la vista en forma de tabla.

Comment: Necesitas varias tablas, al menos tres (personas, poblaciones, resultados)  estas tablas estarían unidas mediante claves llamadas foráneas, luego las unes mediante JOIN para obtener los datos que quieras. Aquí tienes un ejemplo basado en personas, ciudades, provincias y países (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76772f/1) , para que veas como funciona y se podría adaptar facilmente a tu modelo. A la izquierda se crean las tablas y a la derecha una consulta que toma datos de cada una de ellas.

Comment: Si, pero esta vista es el resultado de por lo menos 2 joins, ahora lo que necesito es que muestre el ultimo de cada grupo, y no lo consigo, gracias por responder.

Comment: Recomiendo que te expliques mejor en tu pregunta. _El último de cada grupo..._ Eso tiene sentido para ti, pero no para nosotros. ¿El último qué, de cada grupo de qué? Trata de narrar con palabras lo que quieres hacer para que quienes te leemos podamos entender lo que necesitas y donde te encuentras bloqueado.

Comment: si lo que pasa es que me pone un tope de palabras para poner mi pregunta, pero basicamente la tabla o vista que tengo esta en el enlace http://rextester.com/RFG40822 lo que busco es que me de el resultado que he dibujado en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> necesito que muestre el último resultado de cada ciudad

Según el [rextester](http://rextester.com/RFG40822) que compartistes, concluyo que las agrupaciones de ciudades se determinan por la columna `SuperCodigo`. Y *último resultado* se determina por el registro con el valor más elevado en la columna `Id_Custom` para un grupo de registros con el mismo `SuperCodigo`.

Con eso en mente, se puede lograr haciendo un join con una tabla derivada de sí misma que agrupa por `SuperCodigo` y que junta por `max(Id_Custom)`:

```
select b.* 
  from Bitacora b
  join (select SuperCodigo, max(Id_Custom) as max_id_custom
          from Bitacora
         group by SuperCodigo) g
    on g.SuperCodigo = b.SuperCodigo
   and g.max_id_custom = b.Id_Custom;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/NZVZM82993)</kbd>

Comment: sstan gracias por responder, verás maso menos es así, una tabla Ciudad xEJm tiene los campos: SuperCodigo y Población, y la otra tabla Consumidores tiene: Id_Custom, Nombre, Resultado y tambien SuperCodigo para instanciarlo, haciendo unas modificaciones minimas a tu codigo, te diré que funcionó!!! y como anillo al dedo!... carga toda la data y no se relentiza con funciones y demas procesos innecesarios, muchas Gracias sstan! en verdad te estoy muy agradecido! :D

Comment: me podrías dar una mano con esto?... http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54906/mysql-como-contar-los-campos-de-fecha-y-hora-de-cada-franja-horaria

Comment: Hola @sstan crees que te sea posible echarme una mano con esta?

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96897/mysql-mostrar-en-2-campos-una-consulta-a-un-solo-campo