# ¿MySQL - Como contar los campos de Fecha y Hora de cada franja horaria?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber cómo contar el campo fecha (Ej: `2017-03-12 08:14:12`) que se encuentra en la zona horaria especificada (Entre las 08:00:00 y 08:29:00) y  hasta las 18:00:00 y 18:29:00 y me MUESTRE CERO `"0"` cuando no haya llamadas.

Sólo me muestra las franjas que tienen llamadas, si no hay llamadas no logro que me muestre cero. Pensé en un LEFT JOIN pero no me ha funcionado. Busco que quede más o menos así:

```
|   Franja Horaria   | Conteo |
|08:00:00 - 08:29:00 |    0   |
|08:30:00 - 08:59:00 |   10   |
|09:00:00 - 09:29:00 |    2   |
|09:30:00 - 09:59:00 |    0   |
|10:00:00 - 10:29:00 |    5   |
|10:29:00 - 10:59:00 |    0   |
...
...
|17:30:00 - 17:59:00 |    9   |
|18:00:00 - 18:29:00 |   12   |
```

Adjunto ACTUALIZADO CON CONSULTA: http://rextester.com/TNWN66788

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir un ejemplo concreto de tu tabla con datos? ¿Puedes incluir el SQL que tienes hasta ahora y que deseas mejorar?  ¿Que sucedería con fechas que tienen la hora a medianoche, por ejemplo? ¿ Y que hay de una hora como `08:29:59`, queda excluída?

Comment: Es cierto @sstan ya edite mi pregunta y le agregue una tabla diferidas, tomando el código que viste en la pregunta anterior. de las llamadas obtenidas a las 08:29:59 esta quedaría incluida en la franja de las 08:00:00. Mientras que si fuera 08:59:59 quedaría incluida en la franja de las 08:30:00. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @sstan te mando el siguiente enlace ¿es posible aplicarle un Left Join?

http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55065/mysql-mostrar-0-cuando-no-se-encuentre-registros-en-una-franja-horaria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando que cada día tiene 48 franjas de 30 minutos (0 - 47), se pueden agrupar los registros por *número de franja* de la forma siguiente:

```
select concat(sec_to_time(franja_id * 1800), ' - ', sec_to_time((franja_id+1) * 1800 - 1)) as franja_horario,
       count(franja_id) as conteo
  from (select time_to_sec(
                   timediff(fecha_contacto, cast(date(fecha_contacto) as datetime))
               ) div 1800 as franja_id
          from diferidas) t
 group by franja_id
 order by franja_id;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/UHYQ33754)</kbd>

Nota que el *número de franja* se obtiene obteniendo la cantidad de segundos entre medianoche y la hora de `fecha_contacto`, y luego dividiendo por la cantidad de segundos en 30 minutos (1800 segundos).

Ahora bien, falta resolver tu segundo problema: obtener las franjas con cuenta cero. Para esto, debes establecer la lista de franjas que quieres y definirlas como una tabla al que le puedes hacer un left join.

Una manera de hacer esto es creando una tabla derivada con todos los *números de franja* que te interesan. Como deseas todas las franjas a partir de `08:00:00 - 08:29:59` hasta `18:00:00 - 18:29:59`, esto equivale a las franjas `16` a `36`:

```
select concat(sec_to_time(f.franja_id * 1800), ' - ', sec_to_time((f.franja_id+1) * 1800 - 1)) as franja_horario,
       count(t.franja_id) as conteo
  from (select 16 as franja_id
        union all select 17
        union all select 18
        union all select 19
        union all select 20
        union all select 21
        union all select 22
        union all select 23
        union all select 24
        union all select 25
        union all select 26
        union all select 27
        union all select 28
        union all select 29
        union all select 30
        union all select 31
        union all select 32
        union all select 33
        union all select 34
        union all select 35
        union all select 36) f
  left join (select time_to_sec(
                        timediff(fecha_contacto, cast(date(fecha_contacto) as datetime))
                    ) div 1800 as franja_id
               from diferidas) t
    on t.franja_id = f.franja_id
 group by f.franja_id
 order by f.franja_id;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/MWCWNR45641)</kbd>

O, si prefieras que tu consulta no se *contamine* con esa tabla derivada feíta, puedes crear una tabla dedicada a ese propósito con los datos necesarios:

```
create table Franjas (
  franja_id int not null primary key    
);

insert into Franjas (franja_id)
values (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25),
(26), (27), (28), (29), (30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36);
```

De esta forma, la consulta queda más compacta:

```
select concat(sec_to_time(f.franja_id * 1800), ' - ', sec_to_time((f.franja_id+1) * 1800 - 1)) as franja_horario,
       count(t.franja_id) as conteo
  from Franjas f
  left join (select time_to_sec(
                        timediff(fecha_contacto, cast(date(fecha_contacto) as datetime))
                    ) div 1800 as franja_id
               from diferidas) t
    on t.franja_id = f.franja_id
 group by f.franja_id
 order by f.franja_id;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/MANUV45577)</kbd>

Comment: Me encanto tu respuesta @sstan, añadí un campo fecha para agrupar las llamadas por días y funciona bien, no solo muestra 0 cuando no hay llamadas sino que pone NULL a los días que no tienen registro, estupendo!. Sin embargo cuando le agrego un where al campo Fecha (where t.fechaContacto='2017-03-15') solo muestra las franjas que tienen llamadas, no muestra las franjas horarias con null o 0 si no tienen registros de llamada, y es que con o sin días o registro de llamadas todas las franjas horarias deben mostrarse en la consulta. Gracias de igual modo!

http://rextester.com/GKB36218 CampoFecha

Comment: No entiendo 100% la lógica de agregar un campo fecha si es que varias fechas pueden agruparse dentro de la misma franja horario. Me parece que eso te puede dar resultados inesperados. Pero ignorando eso y centrándome en el problema del `where t.fechaContacto='2017-03-15'`, eso se resuelva fácilmente al no poner la condición en el `where`, si no mas bien en la condición del left join: `on t.franja_id = f.franja_id and t.fechaContacto='2017-03-15'`.

Comment: Es cierto! :o!!! era tan simple como eso!... me sangran los ojos de tanto cansancio xD!!! Veras la fecha será remplazada por una variable que será seleccionada por un usuario atravez de una app. El conteo será un indicador de cuantas llamadas hay por franja -siendo su limite de 12 llamadas por franja- el conteo permitirá a la app y al usuario saber cuanta disponibilidad tiene la franja antes que esta no este disponible, la Franja que el usuario también seleccionará. Permitiendo programar una próxima llamada en la tabla atravez de la selección del usuario. Gracias @sstan otra vez lo hiciste!

Answer (score 2):

Repito la respuesta en tu otra pregunta, que cerraron por duplicada.

No te sirve hacer left join de la tabla con sí misma. Necesitas hacerte una tabla "dummy" que contenga en duro todas las franjas:

```
SELECT '08:30 - 08:59' as franja UNION ALL
SELECT '09:30 - 09:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '10:30 - 10:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '11:30 - 11:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '12:30 - 12:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '13:30 - 13:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '14:30 - 14:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '15:30 - 15:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '16:30 - 16:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '17:30 - 17:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '18:30 - 18:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '19:30 - 19:59'
```

a esta tabla le haces un `LEFT JOIN` con la tabla de contactos reemplazando los nulos con ceros:

```
SELECT franjas.franja, IFNULL(conteo,0) as conteo
FROM franjas LEFT JOIN contactos ON franjas.franja=contactos.franja;
```

Forkié tu ejemplo de rextester con mi propuesta de solución: http://rextester.com/NHNVD11071

Answer (score 1):

Buenos días!

Para empezar creo que lo que necesitas es la funcion `HOUR()`de MySQL, que te devuelve la hora. Incluso si quieres hacerlo por franjas de media hora puedes utilizar la funcion `MINUTE()` para obtener los minutos de un timestamp.

Una vez con esto puedes hacer la consulta sumando los registros que cumplan los IFs, así tendrás la suma por franja horaria.

Por ejemplo, para franjas horarias de horas enteras tendrías algo así:

```
SELECT 
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 0, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_0,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 1, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_1,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 2, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_2,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 3, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_3,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 4, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_4,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 5, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_5,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 6, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_6,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 7, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_7,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 8, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_8,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 9, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_9,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 10, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_10,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 11, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_11,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 12, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_12,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 13, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_13,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 14, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_14,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 15, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_15,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 16, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_16,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 17, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_17,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 18, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_18,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 19, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_19,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 20, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_20,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 21, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_21,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 22, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_22,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 23, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_23
FROM DIFERIDAS T;
```

Bueno y ya para acabar de rizar el rizo esta seria la consulta para ver las llamadas por franjas de media hora desde las 8.00 hasta las 18.00:

```
SELECT 
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 8 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_8_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 8 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_8_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 9 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_9_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 9 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_9_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 10 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_10_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 10 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_10_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 11 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_11_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 11 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_11_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 12 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_12_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 12 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_12_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 13 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_13_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 13 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_13_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 14 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_14_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 14 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_14_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 15 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_15_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 15 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_15_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 16 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_16_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 16 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_16_30,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 17 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 0 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 29, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_17_00,
SUM(if(HOUR(T.TIME_CONTACT) = 17 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) >= 30 and MINUTE(T.TIME_CONTACT) <= 59, 1, 0)) AS FRANJA_17_30
FROM DIFERIDAS T;
```

Comment: Si, pero es un poco más complicado cuando no hay llamadas en una franja tiene que mostrar el valor 0. y son franjas desde las 08:00:00 hasta las 18:00:00 en ciertas franjas no hay llamadas, ¿como le indico a MySql que busque todas las franjas horarias incluyendo las que no tienen llamadas?

Comment: Ahora con la tabla que nos has pasado editando la pregunta edito mi respuesta para que haga lo que realmente necesitas. Era complicado antes sin la tabla real.

Comment: @neojosh2 ya he editado la respuesta usando tu tabla. Esto ahora mostraría las franjas de horas enteras, pero usando la funciona `MINUTE()` podrías facilmente modificar los IFs para contar por franjas de media hora.

Comment: @neojosh2 te he puesto la consulta para las franjas de media hora desde las 8.00 a las 18.00! Espero sea esto lo que necesitas

Comment: si ya lo había editado por minutos y funciona! gracias, buscaba algo más parecido al modelo que puse en el ejemplo de mi pregunta, es para la app a la que tengo que relacionar esta consulta, pero de igual manera servirá, Gracias por contestar tan pronto @Monclus!