# Consulta SQL anual agrupada por fechas

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Necesito realizar una consulta anual agrupada por meses de todos los usuarios registrados en el período de un año. La consulta sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total_users, 
    YEAR(created_at), 
    MONTH(created_at) 
FROM 
    `users` 
WHERE 
    date(`created_at`) >= '2016-03-01 00:00:00' 
    AND date(`created_at`) <= '2017-03-31 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(created_at) ASC, 
    MONTH(created_at) ASC
```

Hasta ahí todo correcto, arroja los resultados esperados, pero necesitaría que además arrojara los meses en los que no hay registros a 0 con su correspondiente mes y año.

**Solución utilizada finalmente**

```
SELECT table_dates.year, table_dates.month, COUNT(id) AS total_registers
FROM `users`
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT 2016 AS year, 3 as month, CONCAT(2016, 3) as identifier UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 4, CONCAT(2016, 4) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 5, CONCAT(2016, 5) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 6, CONCAT(2016, 6) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 7, CONCAT(2016, 7) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 8, CONCAT(2016, 8) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 9, CONCAT(2016, 9) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 10, CONCAT(2016, 10) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 11, CONCAT(2016, 11) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2016, 12, CONCAT(2016, 12) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2017, 1, CONCAT(2017, 1) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2017, 2, CONCAT(2017, 2) UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2017, 3, CONCAT(2017, 3)
) table_dates ON table_dates.identifier = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%c'))
GROUP BY table_dates.year ASC, table_dates.month ASC
ORDER BY `table_dates`.`year` ASC, `table_dates`.`month` ASC
```

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestras aportaciones.

Comment: Comentario aparte: para mayor precisión, y para evitar errores del tipo *cuantos días hay en un mes*, te sugiero convertir la condición `date(created_at) <= '2017-03-31 23:59:59'` a `date(created_at) < '2017-04-01 00:00:00'`.

Comment: Necesitas crear una tabla "dummy" con todos los meses y años que quieres medir, y luego hacer un left join entre esa tabla y tu tabla users. De esa manera obligarás a retornar aunque sea un conteo nulo para las filas sin usuarios. Mira mi respuesta a esta pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54906/mysql-como-contar-los-campos-de-fecha-y-hora-de-cada-franja-horaria/55160#55160

Comment: Lo que comenta @amenadiel es correcto. Si estarías usando otra base de datos que permite consultas recursivas (ejemplo: SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, ...), habría maneras de escribir la consulta sin depender de una tabla "dummy". Pero que yo sepa, con MySQL, no te queda otra.

Comment: @sstan he visto que usan tablas del INFORMATION_SCHEMA para generar filas, y combinadas con una variable, ir incrementando ésta para hacer la tabla dummy con menos código. No me gustó ese método.

Comment: @amenadiel: Exacto. Esas soluciones asumen que ciertas tablas siempre tendrán un cierto mínimo de registros. Me parece muy frágil como diseño. Siempre me fascina la popularidad de MySQL en vista de sus limitaciones y defectos serios en comparación con otras bases de datos.

Comment: @sstan además del hecho, dramático, de que una función MySQL por definición no puede retornar un rowset. En vez de añadir más engines debieran al menos implementar eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que pides, la consulta debe, de alguna manera, obtener o generar una lista de meses fijo para que le puedes hacer un `left join` de los datos en tu tabla `users`, de manera que sin importar los datos en esta, siempre obtengas registros para todos los meses.

Establecer o generar esta lista de meses es la parte que es incómoda con MySQL. Con otras bases de datos, es posible hacer esto de forma relativamente sencilla, sea usando CTEs recursivos, o como en PostgreSQL, usando funciones diseñadas precisamente para eso ([`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)).

Como bien comenta @amenadiel, con MySQL, las opciones son más limitadas.

Por un lado, puedes crear una tabla (de verdad o derivada) con la lista de meses. Pero si las de fechas que te interesa varía de consulta en consulta, tienes que modificar esta tabla a cada vez.

Por otro lado, existen técnicas usando variables y joins con tablas "sistema" que ya existen y en las cuales se asume que tienen un cierto número de registros. En lo personal, estas técnicas me parecen muy fragiles.

Aunque no es ideal, la mejor opción que he encontrado, y que te propongo, se basa en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157776/4955425). La técnica que se usa allí es una combinación de `cross join` y `union all` para establecer una cantidad de registros de base que se puede usar para luego combinarlo con otros `join` o `left join`.

Por ejemplo, la consulta siguiente genera 1000 registros con los números de 0 a 999:

```
select a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) as seq
from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
```

Si asumimos de forma razonable que nunca vas a necesitar considerar más de 1000 meses en una consulta (y de ser necesario, puedes modificar la consulta para que genere más registros), entonces podemos usar la consulta siguiente para generar la lista de fechas a partir de una fecha de comienzo y fin:

```
select dateRange.rangeStart + interval (seq1000.seq) month
from (select date '2016-03-01' as rangeStart, date '2017-04-01' as rangeEnd) dateRange
join (
  select a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) as seq
  from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
  cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
  cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) seq1000
on (dateRange.rangeStart + interval (seq1000.seq) month) < dateRange.rangeEnd
```

Resultado:

```
2016-03-01
2016-04-01
2016-05-01
2016-06-01
2016-07-01
2016-08-01
2016-09-01
2016-10-01
2016-11-01
2016-12-01
2017-01-01
2017-02-01
2017-03-01
```

Y como puedes ver, si necesitas ajustar la fecha de comienzo y fin que te interesa, solo necesitas hacer la modificación dentro de la tabla derivada `dateRange` sin cambiar el resto de la consulta.

Usando lo anterior, podemos combinarlo a tu consulta existente con un `left join`:

```
select count(u.created_at) as total_users,
       year(dateRange.rangeStart + interval (seq1000.seq) month) as created_at_year,
       month(dateRange.rangeStart + interval (seq1000.seq) month) as created_at_month
from (select date '2016-03-01' as rangeStart, date '2017-04-01' as rangeEnd) dateRange
join (
  select a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) as seq
  from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
  cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
  cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) seq1000
on (dateRange.rangeStart + interval (seq1000.seq) month) < dateRange.rangeEnd
left join users u
  on u.created_at >= dateRange.rangeStart
 and u.created_at < dateRange.rangeEnd
 and (dateRange.rangeStart + interval (seq1000.seq) month) = date(u.created_at - interval (day(u.created_at)-1) day)
group by year(dateRange.rangeStart + interval (seq1000.seq) month),
         month(dateRange.rangeStart + interval (seq1000.seq) month)
order by created_at_year, created_at_month
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/RLNN23693)</kbd>

Aunque la consulta no estan tan compacta ni sencilla como quisiera, o como se pudiera lograr usando otras bases de datos, por lo menos cumple el objetivo y es muy sencillo ejecutarlo con diferentes fechas, solo cambiando las fechas en la tabla derivada `dateRange`.

Nota adicional: notarás que a la expresión `date(created_at)` yo le quité el `date()`. No creo que agregarle el `date()` cambie el resultado, pero sí puede tener un efecto negativo en el rendimiento de tu consulta, porque impide que se use cualquier índice definido en esa columna.