# MYSQL - Mostrar en 2 campos una consulta a un solo campo

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de pagos donde en un campo llamado `ESTADO_COMPRA` nos muestra los siguientes valores (`EN CRÉDITO, PENDIENTE DE PAGO`), entonces quiero contar en campos ficticio las que aun tienen crédito y las que ya se vencieron sin pagarse. Algo así.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|Cod_ruc. | nom_empresas.   | Contactados. | EnCredito. | Pendiente |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2045621 | LEXCORP ENT.    |           20 |          1 |         2 |
| 2045577 | Wayne Enterpri. |           35 |          3 |         1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

La tabla original es más o menos así

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| cod_comp | codi_ruc | nombr_empresa | comprado | tipo_pago | Estado_Venta |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| C0000001 | 2045621  | LEXCORP ENT.  |      350 |   15 días | EN CREDITO   |
| C0000002 | 2045621  | LEXCORP ENT.  |      150 |   20 días | VENCIDO      |
| C0000003 | 2045621  | LEXCORP ENT.  |     1150 |   15 días | VENCIDO      |
| C0000004 | 2045577  | WAYNE ENTPR.  |     3520 |   30 días | EN CREDITO   |
| C0000005 | 2045577  | WAYNE ENTPR.  |     4010 |   30 días | PAGADO       |
| C0000006 | 2045577  | WAYNE ENTPR.  |     5050 |   30 días | EN CREDITO   |
| C0000007 | 2045577  | WAYNE ENTPR.  |     2050 |   30 días | VENCIDO      |
| C0000008 | 2045577  | WAYNE ENTPR.  |     2150 |   30 días | EN CREDITO   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Me complico en dividir el conteo de `Estado_Venta` en 2 campos, `En crédito` y `Pendiente`. *Olvidaba mencionar que el campo contactados viene de un JOIN de la tabla LlamadasClientes(contactado,cod_ruc,detalle_llamada), aquí simplemente con un Count(cod_ruc) puedo contar la cantidad de contactos que ha tenido un determinado cliente.

Comment: Para agregar tablas recomiendo esta App Web, la cual te ayuda a generar tablas en ASCII, para poder copiarlas y dar un mejor aspecto a tus preguntas. http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/

Answer (score 1):

Se puede resolver de la siguiente forma:

```
select  p.codi_ruc,
    p.nombr_empresa,
    l.contactados                                                       AS 'Contactados.',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.Estado_Venta = 'EN CREDITO' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'EnCredito.',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.Estado_Venta = 'VENCIDO' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)    AS 'Pendiente '
    from pagos p
    inner join (select cod_ruc, 
                       Count(l.cod_ruc) as contactados
                       from LlamadasClientes
                       group by cod_ruc
        ) l
        on p.codi_ruc = l.cod_ruc
    group by p.codi_ruc,
         p.nombr_empresa, 
         l.contactados
```

Obviamente no pude probarlo, y no sé si la tabla `pagos` se llama efectivamente así, pero es clara la idea, usamos el `count` únicamente para las condiciones que necesitamos, si mal no recuerdo en MySQL el `count(null)` no cuenta, sino se podría reemplazar por un `sum`.

Comment: Gracias por contestar @Patricio Moracho, esta bastante cerca en verdad, pero el resultado no es exacto, la tabla que se me da, tiene filas repetidas, porque la tabla es un histórico de consumidores que renuevan su licencia cada cierto tiempo. No la puedo modificar, solo tomar los datos para filtrar.
Ejm. 
En la tabla Consumidores_registrados un cliente aparece repetido 5 veces
En la tabla llamadasClientes se le llamo 4 veces
En la tabla PAGOS solo hay un pendiente y 0 en crédito,
Con tu formula tiene contactado 8 veces(fueron 4), tiene 0 créditos(ok) y 4 pendientes(debería tener 1)

Comment: Faltaba agregar `l.contactados` al `group by`, igual no creo que ese sea el problema. No entiendo por que retorna 8 registros de `LlamadasClientes`, la sentencia agrupa por `cod_ruc`, es decir si EL `COUNT` te devuelve 8 es por que hay 8 registros x `cod_ruc`, tal vez falte algún filtro y por eso hay más, pero no puede haber 4 registros y luego transformarse en 8 por que no estamos sumando el `COUNT`. Por el lado de los 5 en pendientes, mencionas que en `Consumidores_registrados` hay 5 registros, cual es el `Estado_Venta ` de esos 5 registros? Cualquier cosa nos contactamos por chat. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu campo que quieres separar en 2 tiene este formato (valor1, valor2)
puedes hacer una vista donde agregas todos los datos que quieres mostrar excepto el que quieres dividir y entonces agregas esto a tu vista

```
SELECT
tabla.id,
tabla.campo1,
tabla.campo2,
select TRIM(SUBSTR(campo3,2,INSTR(campo3,",")-2)) as subcampo1,
TRIM(SUBSTR("campo3,INSTR(campo3,",")+2,INSTR(campo3,")")-INSTR("campo3",",")-2)) as subcampo2
FROM
mitabla
```

Los campos que mantendrias serian id,campo1,y campo3.
Posteriormente identifico campo3 como el campo que tiene los valores que voy a separar, posteriormente lo que hago es separar ambos valores en dos campos diferentes llamados subcampo1 y subcampo2 en tu caso lo llamarias **En Crédito** y **Pendiente**. Para dividirlos solamente busqué en la cadena el delimitador que me separaba ambos valores que en este caso era la coma y comence a tomar el primer valor desde el comienzo, sin contar el **(** hasta la **,** y el segundo valor desde la **,** hasta el final sin contar el **)**, si no es este el formato que empleas puedes explicarlo mejor para darte la solución exacta de todas formas solo cambiaría muy poco de la respuesta que te doy.

Comment: Me parece que OP lo que tiene es en un solo campo los dos valores.. lo que quiere es que su consulta final tenga 2 columnas con la suma indistinta de ese campo, para cada caso..

Comment: así es gbianchi, puedo usar alias para el where, pero hay un JOIN a otra tabla, aunque no tiene mucho que ver, al hacer el WHERE con los alias teniendo un JOIN en la cadena, no hace la busqueda por alias... :'(