# MySQL - Mostrar 0 cuando no se encuentre registros en una Franja Horaria

Tags: mysql

Buenas, quisiera saber como contar el campo fecha (Ejm: 2017-03-12 08:14:12) que se encuentra en la zona horaria especificada (Entre las 08:00:00 y 08:29:00) y  hasta las 18:00:00 y 18:29:00 y me MUESTRE CERO "0" cuando no halla llamadas, pero solo me muestra las franjas que tienen llamadas, si no hay llamadas no logro que me muestre cero, pense en un LEFT JOIN pero no me ha funcionado, busco que quede mas o menos así:

|---Franja Horaria----|-Conteo-|
|08:00:00 - 08:29:00 |--- 0------|
|08:30:00 - 08:59:00 |---10-----|
|09:00:00 - 09:29:00 |----2------|
|09:30:00 - 09:59:00 |----0------|
|10:00:00 - 10:29:00 |----5------|
|10:29:00 - 10:59:00 |----0------|
...
...
|17:30:00 - 17:59:00 |----9------|
|18:00:00 - 18:29:00 |----12----|

Adjunto ACTUALIZADO CON CONSULTA: http://rextester.com/TNWN66788

Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Comment: Si escribes lo que tienes actualmente te podrán ayudar mejor.

Comment: Tienes que generar un rango de fechas con intervalos de 30 minutos

Comment: Hola @neojosh2. Estás publicando la misma pregunta que hiciste hace 18 horas. Por favor intenta evitar generar contenido duplicado en el sitio, y convendría que revises las respuestas que recibiste, comentándolas, votándolas y aceptando alguna según corresponda.

Comment: gracias y disculpa la molestia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te sirve hacer left join de la tabla con sí misma. Necesitas hacerte una tabla "dummy" que contenga en duro todas las franjas:

```
SELECT '08:30 - 08:59' as franja UNION ALL
SELECT '09:30 - 09:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '10:30 - 10:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '11:30 - 11:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '12:30 - 12:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '13:30 - 13:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '14:30 - 14:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '15:30 - 15:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '16:30 - 16:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '17:30 - 17:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '18:30 - 18:59' UNION ALL
SELECT '19:30 - 19:59'
```

a esta tabla le haces un `LEFT JOIN` con la tabla de contactos reemplazando los nulos con ceros:

```
SELECT franjas.franja, IFNULL(conteo,0) as conteo
FROM franjas LEFT JOIN contactos ON franjas.franja=contactos.franja;
```

Forkié tu ejemplo de rextester con mi propuesta de solución: http://rextester.com/NHNVD11071

Comment: Estoy votando para cerrar la pregunta como duplicada de la que el mismo autor hizo previamente ([¿MySQL - Como contar los campos de Fecha y Hora de cada franja horaria?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/54906/127)) ... quizás te interese publicar la respuesta ahí en vez de en esta pregunta.

Comment: @mariano voy a revisarla. A lo mejor ya tiene una respuesta igual o mejor que esta, que es muy poco elegante

Comment: No les presté mucha atención, sólo estaba de paso por las revisiones, pero como sea, siempre viene bien tener diferentes respuestas a una misma pregunta

Comment: estoy de acuerdo, y gracias por tu respuesta @amenadiel se acerco a la solución en un 89%. Gracias de igual modo.